# Directive works with TemplateUrl but not Template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

This is a strange one. I am new to angular, only been learning for a week or so.

I have two directives.

The first:

```
app.directive('block', function() {
   return {
       restrict: 'E',
       replace: true,
        scope:true,
       link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
           scope.blockCss = function() {
                return attrs.block;
           }
           scope.blockSize = function() {
                return attrs.blocksize;
           }
           scope.category = function() {
                return attrs.category;
           }
       },
       templateUrl: function(elem,attrs) {
           return attrs.block + '.html';
       }
   }
});
```

This works perfectly on an element called:

```
<block blocksize="3" category="foo1" blockcss="bar1"></block>
```

Now the kicker.

An *identical* directive but changing from TemplateUrl to Template so as to have something more dynamic:

```
app.directive('block', function() {
   return {
       restrict: 'E',
       replace: true,
        scope:true,
       link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
           scope.blockCss = function() {
                return attrs.block;
           }
           scope.blockSize = function() {
                return attrs.blocksize;
           }
           scope.category = function() {
                return attrs.category;
           }
       },
       template: function(elem,attrs) {

           return '<div class="blocksize{{blockSize()}} {{blockCss()}}" ng-repeat="item in items | orderByPriority | filter:{category:category()} | orderBy:myorder" ng-include src="\'{{blockCss()}}.html\'"></div>';
       }
   }
});
```

I might be an idiot but if someone could point out to me what I am missing I would appreciate it.

Further to the above, I would like to be able to refer to the attributes in the element (e.g. the 'block' element) inside the template or template URL - that is why I have the scope definitions (which need to be scope children).

Really looking forward to any kind of reply.

Comment: i don't think you can use template as a function and in your case it doesn't make sense anyways, so you would better off using just template:"string"

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. That helped it a long a little. I still cant get the attribute of the root element into the ng-include template though. Any way for me to do that?

Comment: @DayanMorenoLeon you can actually use a function for a template, the function just needs to return a string.  But I still don't get what the OP wants to do

Comment: hey can you point me to that part of the docs? i haven;t seen that functionallity documented and it would be pretty interesting, you can do interesting things with it